# Azure CI using alternative nuget feed

Tags: c#, azure, nuget, azure-web-app-service, nuget-package

I'm trying to get Azure to check an alternative nuget feed for packages as well as the default one.

I have configured my CI to auto deploy to an azure webapp when i check into source control.

My solution uses a few nuget packages which are currently only on the Azure nightly feed. I've changed my nuget.targets file as below to include both the nightlies feed and the default nuget feed.

```
<ItemGroup Condition=" '$(PackageSources)' == '' ">
    <!-- Package sources used to restore packages. By default, registered sources under %APPDATA%\NuGet\NuGet.Config will be used -->
    <!-- The official NuGet package source (https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/) will be excluded if package sources are specified and it does not appear in the list -->
    <PackageSource Include="http://www.myget.org/F/azure-appservice/api/v2/" />
    <PackageSource Include="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
</ItemGroup>
```

However when I checkin it fails, and looking at the Activity Logs in Azure I can see that it has failed to find the nightly packages as it's not looking in the the `http://www.myget.org/F/azure-appservice/api/v2/` feed

```
Command: "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
Handling .NET Web Application deployment.
MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '14.0' from 'D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin'.
Feeds used:
  C:\DWASFiles\Sites\#1<REDACTED>__43ae\LocalAppData\NuGet\Cache
  D:\local\UserProfile\.nuget\packages\
  https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

Restoring NuGet package Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.1.1.2-alpha-10245.
Restoring NuGet package Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.1.0.2-alpha-10232.
Restoring NuGet package Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Core.1.1.2-alpha-10245.
WARNING: Unable to find version '1.0.2-alpha-10232' of package 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions'.
WARNING: Unable to find version '1.1.2-alpha-10245' of package 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs'.
WARNING: Unable to find version '1.1.2-alpha-10245' of package 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Core'.
Restoring NuGet package Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.SendGrid.1.0.2-alpha-10232.
WARNING: Unable to find version '1.0.2-alpha-10232' of package 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.SendGrid'.
Unable to find version '1.0.2-alpha-10232' of package 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.SendGrid'.
Unable to find version '1.1.2-alpha-10245' of package 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Core'.
Unable to find version '1.1.2-alpha-10245' of package 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs'.
Unable to find version '1.0.2-alpha-10232' of package 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions'.
Failed exitCode=1, command=nuget restore "D:\home\site\repository\<REDACTED>.sln"
An error has occurred during web site deployment.
Unable to find version '1.0.2-alpha-10232' of package 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.SendGrid'.\r\nUnable to find version '1.1.2-alpha-10245' of package 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Core'.\r\nUnable to find version '1.1.2-alpha-10245' of package 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs'.\r\nUnable to find version '1.0.2-alpha-10232' of package 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions'.\r\nC:\Program Files (x86)\SiteExtensions\Kudu\52.50316.2137\bin\scripts\starter.cmd "D:\home\site\deployments\tools\deploy.cmd"
```

Does anyone know how to configure this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per matthews reply https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/663

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <solution>
    <add key="disableSourceControlIntegration" value="true" />
  </solution>
    <packageRestore>
        <!--Allow NuGet to download missing packages -->
        <add key="enabled" value="True" />
        <!-- Automatically check for missing packages during build in Visual Studio -->
        <add key="automatic" value="True" />
    </packageRestore>
    <packageSources>
        <add key="nuget.org" value="https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/" />
        <add key="azure_app_service" value="https://www.myget.org/F/azure-appservice/api/v2" />
        <!--<add key="buildTools" value="https://www.myget.org/F/30de4ee06dd54956a82013fa17a3accb/" />-->
    </packageSources>
</configuration>
```